# SharePoint calendar does not show all events from the past months post migration in calendar view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-calendar

I migrated some calendars for a client from SharePoint 2007 to Office 365. The issue is in calendar view, certain entered items are not at all visible but when I switch the view to All Events view, I can see those items that are not appearing in the calendar view, I did check the view settings and Show all items is checked for the calendar view, does someone know the reason why calendar is not listing events on the calendar view?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.